# Adding to DateTime with value created from createFromFormat not returning expected value

Tags: php, datetime

I'm playing around with the DateTime functionality in PHP, and I've hit a stumbling block that I can't explain.

Given the following two pieces of code, I would expect that they would put out the same value (2001-01-01), but the second block of code instead outputs 1 year from the date that the code is run (so for today, 15-01-2016). How can I get the second code block to output the expected value?

```
$date = new DateTime('2001-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
$date->format('d-m-Y'); // 01-01-2000, works as expected.

$date = new DateTime();
$date->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2001-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
$date->format('d-m-Y'); // 15-01-2016, output not what is expected.
```

I'm using PHP 5.6.4 on OSX 10.10, installed using Homebrew.

Comment: My output is: `01-01-2002 and 15-01-2016`

Comment: createFromFormat **returns** a new DateTime object with the value you are expecting. It doesn't set the date/time on the current object. Usually it is used as a static object like `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of i don't get the same output as you do:

```
01-01-2002
15-01-2016
```

The first example should be pretty clear, you create a `DateTime` Object and add 1 year to it so from `01-01-2001` it get's `01-01-2002`

In the second on it's pretty easy too, you just forgot to assign the value from `createFromFormat()`, so the `DateTime` just uses the current date e.g. `15-01-2015` and adds 1 year.

So just change this:

```
$date->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2001-01-01');
```

to this:

```
$date = $date->createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2001-01-01');
```

Comment: It would be better to use static method `DateTime::createFromFormat()` rather than this public one, since this method cannot be found anywhere in the manual, and god knows if it will work in next release...